# Local npm install doesn't create symlink to "bin" executables

Tags: node.js, npm-install

If I create a minimal `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "cli-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "bin": "index.js",
  "main": "index.js"
}
```

and an `index.js` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
console.log("Hello")
```

and run `npm install`, why doesn't `npm` create a `./node_modules/.bin/cli-test` symlink to my `index.js` file? [The package.json documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) says this on "bin":

> On install, npm will symlink that file into `prefix/bin` for global installs, or `./node_modules/.bin`  for local installs.

If I do `npm install -g`, a symlink is created, but I don't want a global install. I'm using node 6.10.3 and npm 3.10.10. Also tried with npm 5.0.4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running `npm install` inside a package directory (which is what you're doing) only installs a package's dependencies, not the package itself:

> **npm install** (in package directory, no arguments):
>
> Install the dependencies in the local node_modules folder.

(from `npm help install`)

The documentation that you're quoting refers to the package *itself* being installed.

I typically put executable scripts in `./bin` of a package directory, so I can execute them directly, and refer to them from `package.json`:

```
"bin" : { "my-cool-cli" : "./bin/my-cool-cli" }
```